# Why methods from algorithm with execution policy and explicit template do not compile?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

This compiles:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
class Test
{
    Test()
    {
        double* a;
        std::copy<double*, double*>(a, a, a);
        std::copy(std::execution::seq, a, a, a);
    }
};
```

but this does not:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
class Test
{
    Test()
    {
        double* a;
        std::copy<std::execution::sequenced_policy, double*, double*>(std::execution::seq, a, a, a);
    }
};
```

MSVC yields error
"no instance of overloaded function 'std::copy' matches the argument list
argument types are (const std::execution::sequenced_policy, double *, double *, double *)"

Please help me understand why.

Comment: What errors do you get? Why do you try to specify template arguments here in the first place?

Comment: When asking about compiler errors please include the full text of the compiler error and the compiler, version and command line parameters

Comment: "This compiles" - [no it doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/T1qa4c754)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Because Cython compiles corresponding Python code into C++ code with templates

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to call `std::copy` from python, and it only works with explicitly specified template arguments?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Not quite. I'm calling std::copy from Python as it is described in this guide https://github.com/shwina/stdpar-cython/blob/main/jacobi.ipynb and it compiles into a call with explicit template arguments, which yields same error as this simple example.

Comment: @rx303 You should probably ask a new question about this specific problem (not being able to call it from Python), and attach your Python code. This somewhat smells of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/353058).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I'll probably will. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The policy parameter is [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to be `ExecutionPolicy &&policy`, and [`std::execution::seq`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag) `inline constexpr std::execution::sequenced_policy seq`.

Since `policy` is a forwarding reference, `ExecutionPolicy` would be deduced to `const std::execution::sequenced_policy &`, which is what you need to pass.

---

But note that it's a bad idea to explicitly pass template arguments to functions that normally deduce them.

In this case the template parameters seem to be documented, but it isn't always the case, and can depend on the standard library implementation.

And it adds unnecessary confusion, as was shown here.

Comment: For OP: it compiles with `const &`: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4TGGG3jqW)

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes, this might help, thanks.